# Show only matched node(s) in jsTree

Tags: jquery, jstree, jstree-search

I have a common code based on class selector for jsTree plugin. I used jsTree in another cshtml page. I want to display only matched node from search in jsTree. I already set the option to show only matched nodes but it is not working.

Can any one please help me?

```
$(".jsTree").each(function (index, element) {
    if ($(element).data("isProcessed") != "1" && $(element).attr("isProcessed") != 1) {
        $(element).data("isProcessed", "1");
        $(element).attr("isProcessed", "1");
        $(this).jstree({
            core:
            {
                check_callback: true
            },
            checkbox:
            {
                keep_selected_style: true,
                three_state: ($(element).data("three-state") == "false" ? false : true)
            },
            search:
            {
                case_insensitive: true,
                show_only_matches: true
            },
            plugins: ["checkbox", "search"]
        }).on('search.jstree', function (nodes, str, res) {
            if (str.nodes.length === 0) {
                $(element).jstree(true).hide_all();
            }
        });
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#jsroletree_search').keyup(function () {
        $('#jsRoleTree').jstree(true).show_all();
        $('#jsRoleTree').jstree('search', $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please check this https://jsfiddle.net/xfn8aa19/

Comment: I tried it. It did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue in common code sometimes `jsTree` not allowing one more instance on the same page.

Can you please replace your code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#jsroletree_search').keyup(function () {
        $('#jsRoleTree').jstree(true).show_all();
        $('#jsRoleTree').jstree('search', $(this).val());
    });
});
```

To

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#jsroletree_search').keyup(function () {
    $('#jsRoleTree').jstree(true).show_all();
    $('#jsRoleTree').jstree('search', $(this).val());
    $('#jsRoleTree .jstree-hidden').hide();    
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help! It's working but it also display unmatched child node.

Comment: Okay @HarviPatel give me some updating code soon.

Comment: Hi, @HarviPatel can you please check the updated code?

Comment: Hello @jishansiddique, Now it's working fine. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome @HarviPatel Glad to help you :)